# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxHelper.nativeSetApkPath:

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, cocos2d-x, native-methods

**Edit-2**

Finally fixed the error see my answer bellow.

**Edit-1**

Now Created a new project and import it to adt
and add src from property->android->library
as i added library its compile and now created libcocos2dcpp.so file

and ad this to myapp.java file

```
System.loadLibrary("cocos2dcpp");
```

run it and install it on simulator its given the same error

```
08-14 08:05:19.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1425): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxHelper.nativeSetExternalAssetPath:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
08-14 08:05:19.792: E/AndroidRuntime(1425):     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxHelper.nativeSetExternalAssetPath(Native Method)
```

---

I am using cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.3
NDK -- android-ndk-r9d
ANDROID SDK -- android-19
Using MAC OS -- Version 10.9.4

add my project to adt by Import project.

edit the build_native.sh and add

```
# paths
NDK_ROOT="/Users/YourMacName/Documents/android-ndk-r9d"
```

at the start of  the file.

My Android.mk file is

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := game_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/GamePlayScene.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/GameMenu.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AEHero.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/Object.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AEGroundElement.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/LevelGenerator.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AEAirElement.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AEGetShellEffect.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AEPowerUp.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/EnemiesGamePlay.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/EnemyObject.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AEGameManager.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AEStoreMenu.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AEMagnet.cpp  \
           ../../Classes/AEGroundElementNew.cpp  \
           ../../Classes/GameModeSelectionScreen.cpp  \
           ../../Classes/HowToPlay.cpp



LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes                   

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static cocos_extension_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android) \
$(call import-module,cocos2dx) \
$(call import-module,extensions)
```

Added cocos2dx library property->java build path->Link Source->src

Added this code in myApp.java file for load libgame.so file

```
static 
    {
        try 
        {
            System.loadLibrary("game");
        }
        catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ule) 
        {
            Log.e("JNI", "WARNING: Could not load libgame.so");
        }
    }
```

Added this code in Manifest file

```
<!-- Tell Cocos2dxActivity the name of our .so -->
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                   android:value="game" />
```

This is the screenshot of my app bundle

[image]

Its run successfully on genymotion emmulator and on android device error message popup that

```
Unfortunately, myApp has stoped.
```

and error in LogCat is

```
08-13 09:46:19.406: E/JNI(1320): WARNING: Could not load libgame.so
08-13 09:46:19.410: W/dalvikvm(1320): No implementation found for native Lorg/cocos2dx/lib/Cocos2dxHelper;.nativeSetApkPath:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
08-13 09:46:19.414: D/AndroidRuntime(1320): Shutting down VM
08-13 09:46:19.414: W/dalvikvm(1320): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4b53648)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxHelper.nativeSetApkPath:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxHelper.nativeSetApkPath(Native Method)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxHelper.init(Cocos2dxHelper.java:63)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:59)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at com.burninape.hobbitjetpackrunner.hobbit.onCreate(hobbit.java:106)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-13 09:46:19.414: E/AndroidRuntime(1320):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

***My Question is How the libgame.so file is generate ??***

There is no file generated named libgame.so in my `libs` folder

**Its working fine in iOS.**

I had tried creating new app in cocos2dx 2.2.2 and its work perfectly but my app is in cocos2d-2.0-x-2.0.3 and i can't convert whole code to cocos2dx 2.2.2 because its too long.

there are so many liks posted but there is no solution given ,i tried a lot ,if i got the solution i will post the solution for sure.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried running build_native.sh script in console?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Tried and got an error - sudo: ./build_native.sh: command not found.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got the answer after lot of work arround

**All in one you have to run the command ./build_native.sh defore cocos2dx 2.2.2 to generate .so file.**

The sollution was libgame.so file was not created

1)set the ndk path in build_native.sh

2)run the command ./build_native.sh from terminal ,got the error
         `In constructor 'CocosDenshion::SimpleAudioEngine::SimpleAudioEngine()':`
i don't know why but NDK r9 is not compiling the `LOGD` in the cpp file so i remove it from that file.

3)again run the command ./build_native.sh and the result is the libgame.so file is generated 
[image]

4)open the app from eclipse and every thing is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your jni file here? example "main.cpp" in default cocos example library.
I am guessing the wrong namespace provided and thus Android cant find the correct JNI method.

```
 void Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeInit(JNIEnv*  env, jobject thiz, jint w, jint h)
{
    if (!CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getOpenGLView())
    {
        CCEGLView *view = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();
        view->setFrameSize(w, h);

        AppDelegate *pAppDelegate = new AppDelegate();
        pAppDelegate->setScreenId(screenId);

        delegate = pAppDelegate;
        CCApplication::sharedApplication()->run();
    }
    /*
    else
    {
        ccDrawInit();
        ccGLInvalidateStateCache();

        CCShaderCache::sharedShaderCache()->reloadDefaultShaders();
        CCTextureCache::reloadAllTextures();
        CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->postNotification(EVNET_COME_TO_FOREGROUND, NULL);
        CCDirector::sharedDirector()->setGLDefaultValues(); 
    }
     */
}
```